# creating a callback struct to pass into the LuaJIT FFI

Tags: c++, dll, lua, ffi, luajit

So first I load in a DLL I need

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
local theDLL = ffi.load("thisDLL")
```

in the ffi cdef I have two different kinds of structs

```
ffi.cdef [[
    typedef struct StructSession StructSession;
    typedef struct {
        /*
        * begin_proj callback
        */
        bool (__cdecl *begin_proj)(char *proj);

        /*
        * save_proj_state
        */
        bool (__cdecl *save_proj_state)(unsigned char **buffer, int *len);
    } StructCallbacks;
```

I also have this function in the cdef

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl start_session(StructSession **session,
                                                           StructCallbacks *cb);
```

Now I would like to call this function

```
print(theDLL.start_session(a,b))
```

vars a and b are obviously placeholders, the question is how can I pass the structs the function needs? And say we get StructSession working, is making a callback to a function WITHIN LuaJIT even going to be possible for StructCallbacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating the `StructCallbacks` is easy; you can create it with `ffi.new` and create FFI callbacks for the fields (see the [FFI semantics](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html) for information on callbacks).

Creating the `StructSession` is trickier since it's an opaque type, but it's not much different from how you would do it in C.

Here is how you would create one in C:

```
StructSession* S = NULL;
start_session(*S, foo);
```

Notice how you are not directly allocating a `StructSession`. Instead, you allocate a pointer to one, and let `start_session` allocate the actual struct.

So we now translate this to LuaJIT code:

```
local S = ffi.new("StructSession*")
lib.start_session(getPointer(S), foo) -- getPointer should take the pointer of S, but...
```

...the FFI doesn't provide any way to take the pointer of an object (This is intentional; it allows for optimizations).

So how do we get a pointer to a `StructSession`? Well, recall that arrays are convertible to pointers, and we can access those through the FFI. So we instead create a single-slot array of pointers and pass that to `start_session`:

```
local S_slot = ffi.new("StructSession*[1]")
lib.start_session(S_slot, foo)
local S = S_slot[0]
```

And now you have a `StructSession` object.